# How do I compare two columns in a Pandas DataFrame and output values from other columns based on the match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe.

```
A: 3, 4, 1, 2, 1,
B 1, 2, 3, 4
C Red, Blue, Yellow, Green
D Yes, No, Maybe, True
```

what I want to be able to do is sequentially check column A against column B, if there is a match then output C and D relative to B.

For example the data frame above would be converted into
A Yellow, Green, Red, Blue, Red
B Maybe, True, Yes, No, Yes

I am rather new to python and pandas so I might be missing something simple here but I cannot think of solutions for this problem and am unsure where to start to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated

-Smoggs

Many various ideas. I know I should be using iloc to target the value in the cell, but I am unsure how to output the result next to it. I'm really at a loss here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you need to index columns according to another (like here B relative to C and D), you can use the [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method on B.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [3, 4, 1, 2],
    "B": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "C": ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"],
    "D": ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", True]
})

df.set_index("B", inplace=True)
```

Note the `inplace` parameter which directly perform changes on `df` variable.

Then, you can get C and D using A indices:

```py
print(df.loc[df["A"]][["C", "D"]])
# output:
#         C      D
# B               
# 3  Yellow  Maybe
# 4   Green   True
# 1     Red    Yes
# 2    Blue     No
```

Note that we use `loc` and not `iloc` here. The difference is that `loc` will use the dataframe index (even if string are used) whereas `iloc` will use position in the underlying data array (see the doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) for more details).